# How can I remove or add a column in an sql script file?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-scripts

I have an outdated sql insert into script with bunch of datas and I want to import this to the new database which has more columns between the old columns.

Comment: New database , new schema? new server?

Answer (score 0):

You should have been more precise while asking this question.
I cant understand what are you trying to do here.
But i think this will help you
Following is the standard sql insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Just add your column names and data for those columns sequentially and it should work fine

For instance if your old query is

```
insert into <table_name>(col1,col2) values('col1 value','col2 value');
```

And you want to add col3

```
insert into <table_name>(col1,col2,col3) values('col1 value','col2 value','col3 value');
```

and this should work fine.

Comment: As I said I have thousands of datas.

Comment: I think you can use stored procedure in that case.